# PHP Undefined variable in echo function

Tags: php

I have this code for `index.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<?PHP 

if(isset($_GET['page'])){

    require dirname(__FILE__).'/modules/'.$_GET['page'].'/main.php';

} else {

    require dirname(__FILE__).'/modules/home.php';

}

?>
</html>
```

main.php:

```
$title = 'title test';
$description = 'desc test';
$keyword = 'keys test';

echo _is_header_();
```

header function:

```
function _is_header_(){

     require ABSPATH.'/templates/'.TEMPLATENAME.'/header.php';

}
```

In header.php I have meta html tag for `title` and echo `$title` for show title of page. but I see this error :

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: title in
```

how do fix this error?!

**NOTE**: when I replace `require ABSPATH.'/templates/'.TEMPLATENAME.'/header.php';`
 with `echo _is_header_();` my code worked true and show my title.

Comment: and `$lang` is defined where?

Comment: @AnkurTiwari: read `NOTE` in my Q.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: in top of my `index.php`.

Comment: errr... um... ok. Well, when someone posts code, I take it literally. So, I hate to nitpick here, but I don't see where you started the session, and if you did in fact wrap that session array in PHP. I won't be able to go on any further with this, sorry.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: i add `NOTE` for this case SO `$lang` Ineffective. i remove `$lang`...

Comment: see the answer given, I have no other idea as to what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script

```
ABSPATH.'/templates/'.TEMPLATENAME.'/header.php';
```

write a

```
global $title;
```

just befor the line you use it first time.

Answer (score 0):

If your file "header.php" manipulates the variable "$title" or her not exists, then do you  have prints her first, before to include this file.